# Can I use an iMac 2014 as a display for a Mac mini

Tags: target-display

I would like to use my iMac 2014 as a display for a Mac mini that I intend to buy.

Will this work?

Comment: See this [Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) for full details.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your 2014 iMac has to be a mid year model. The late models do not have target display mode.

You do realize you will need two keyboards for this to work. One for the Mac mini and one to put the iMac in target display mode.

I assume the Mac mini is a 2018 year model. This model does not have any Thunderbolt 1 or 2 ports. There are USB-C ports where Thunderbolt 3 devices can be attached.

So, if this is going to work, you will need an adaptor. Apple sells a [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) for 49 USD. Next, you will need a thunderbolt 2 cable. Apple sells an [Apple Thunderbolt Cable (0.5 m) - White](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD862LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-05-m) for 29 USD. This is rather short, so you might want the [Apple Thunderbolt Cable (2.0 m) - White](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD861LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-20-m) for 39 USD.

So, 49 USD + 29 USD = 78 USD. You can buy a [new 21.5" 1920 x 1080 monitor](https://www.microcenter.com/product/602563/acer-ka220hq-215-full-hd-60hz-hdmi-dvi-vga-tn-led-display) for 70 USD. Granted, this monitor does not come with a  HDMI cable, so you might need to buy one.

> The point is, you can buy a new monitor with the same size and resolution for about the same cost as the adaptor plus cable needed to use your old iMac as a display.

Note: the 2018 mac mini does have a internal speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you can use the iMac 2014 with Target Display, to do this you need to use a Thunderbolt 2 cable.

I would suggest given this is untested you buy the computer from a store with a flexible return policy.

Also worth noting that the computer doesn't turn off when you use is as a display so you will have a computer powered on doing nothing.

Note: You can toggle Target Display mode on the iMac using the keyboard command <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> on the iMac, not the Mac mini

Answer (score 0):

Target Display Mode requires two things:

- A supported iMac - your 2014 iMac falls in that category
- High Sierra or *earlier*.  It does not work on Mojave or later.  If you've upgraded, it will not work

There is no OS requirement for the source computer.

You can get full details from the Apple Support Document [Use your iMac as a display with target display mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)