# MBP 2016 + iMac 21 (mid 2011) using a thunderbolt 2->HDMI cable and an HDMI->type C adapter?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I was wondering if that would work? I've found out this to be the cheapest option for me, albeit an awkward one.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these adaptors are design to output to a HDMI TV or monitor. The idea of going backwards and have the HDMI converted as input to a Mac is invalid.

Also, there is more going here than just using the Mac as a display. Each Mac gets access to the to the drives on the other Mac. You can also share the screen on the Mac being used as a display. For example, below is a image of what is was shown on the display of a 2013 iMac. This Mac was in Target Display mode. In other words, the 2013 Mac was being used as a second monitor connected to a another Mac. In the image, you can see the other Mac was using the Screen Sharing application. The Screen Sharing application window is showing the desktop of the 2013 iMac.

[image]

P.S. Before you run out an buy the correct adaptors and cables, you might want to read [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381793/can-i-use-an-imac-2014-as-a-display-for-a-mac-mini/381827#381827) to the question [Can I use an iMac 2014 as a display for a Mac mini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381793/can-i-use-an-imac-2014-as-a-display-for-a-mac-mini).